# How to get one single django queryset by giving multiple tuples

Tags: python, mysql, django, pandas, django-queryset

I have a dataframe of related values that I need to query my object together. I can loop through this list of related values and give them to my object, and then append them to a list, but this gives me a list of separate querysets. Is there a way I can read in my tuples together without a loop and obtain a single queryset?

The related values are hts_run and variant. In this case, the same variant value has multiple hts_run values. my dataframe has removed the unwanted hts_run values, so I have the correct variant corresponding to the correct hts_run value.

here is my code at the moment:

```
var_obj = []
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    v_obj = row['variant']
    var_obj.append(VariantSampleRun.objects.filter(sample=current_sample, 
    hts_run=row['run']).select_related('variant').order_by('variant'))
```

I need however a single var_obj queryset for another function. I have tried to use 'chain' to merge them, but I am thinking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i'm understand you may use `__in` filter, like this:

```
runs = [row['run'] for i, row in df.iterrows()]
var_obj = VariantSampleRun.objects.filter(sample=current_sample,
    hts_run__in=runs).select_related('variant').order_by('variant')
```

Comment: unfortunately not. I have basically have two runs: run1 and run2. all of the variants are found in both runs, i just have selected the variant i want. For example:   variant 1  -  run2,
variant1 - run2
variant2 - run1
variant2 - run2
variant3 -run1
variant3 - run2

I have selected so that the variant on the run I want is in the dataframe:

variant1 - run1
variant2 - run1
variant3 - run2

So when I do that query, I still get all of the variants out for each run, as I am querying all variants from both runs

Answer (score 0):

instead of `df.iterrows()` you just execute

```
runs=model.objects.filter().values_list('run', flat=True)
```

then pass tuple to next filter like

```
filter(hts_run__in=runs)
```